# How to use Ampère's law in this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetostatics

I want to prove that the magnetic field inside a cylindrical cavity in a long, cylindrical conductor carrying uniformly distributed current i and having radius R is uniform. The radius of cavity is 'a' and it's axis is parallel to the main conductor axis. However the axis of cavity is not coaxial with main conductor.

My attempt- I was able to think that the ampèrian loop should be rectangular with two long sides of length L and two short sides of length less than the radius of cavity. Now if one of the longer side is along the axis of cavity, the other longer side should be parallel to this and to ensure that the line integral along shorter side does not contribute significantly, we may take the longer side very long. After this I am having confusion in proving that the magnetic field at center of cavity is same as that at a off axis  point. I am having confusion with directions and magnitudes of the field along sides of rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard "trick" question. You compute the field due inside the fat conductor carrying a uniform current I amps per unit area and  ignoring the cavity. This is a standard Ampere law calculation and gives you circumferential field proportional  to the distance from  center of the fat conductor. You then compute the field due a thin conductor inside the fat one and carrying uniform current density -I amps  per square meter. Again  this is an easy calculation. Superpose the two currents and you have no current in the overlap (cavity). The total field is the sum of the two fields, and is easy to compute in the cavity.

Comment: How does your solution prove that the magnetic field inside the cavity is uniform? I have already calculated the field at the center of cavity using superposition principle like you have explained and now I want to further prove that the same field is present at all points inside cavity using ampere's law.

Comment: you have explicit formulae for the two fields everywhere in the cavity. If you have computed them correctly, ypu should immediately see that their sum is constant vector.